# Best way to make LEDs flash in time with a music source

Tags: led

Could someone suggest the best circuit to make LEDs flash in time with a music source directly connected to the circuit? BTW the circuit needs to run off batteries, I've seen circuits using TIP31 transistors, but are they any good?

Comment: Best is subjective. Tip 31 is a crude hack with only volume affecting the leds. Google color organ for proper methods.

Comment: you could do an FFT transform, and react based on frequency.

Comment: Here's a [kit from Jameco](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_2155541_-1); but they also publish [the schematic](http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2155541Schematic.pdf).  I've build two, and they work fine.  Even if it's not exactly what you are looking for, it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a website for analog audio circuitry that I really like: https://sound-au.com

In keeping with the author's request, I've only provided a link to the home page, but if you add these to the end of the URL, you'll get:

- /project60.htm

  - LED volume meter
- /project136.htm

  - Real-Time Analyser (RTA), basically a full spectrum of what's happening at the moment
- /project62.htm

  - Complete lighting system, including a "Sound to Light" (S2L) module at the bottom of /project62a.htm

Perhaps you could adapt one of those?

---

Or if all you want is to flash a single LED in sync with, say, the kick drum, then you could use a dual opamp to:

1. Lowpass the signal so you're more likely to trigger on the kick rather than the hihat
2. Compare the result to some reference level

The result of that can either drive the LED directly if the opamp is strong enough, or feed a transistor.

Comment: Great website suggestion, I think project 60 is a winner, the others looked way to complicated for what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a very cool chip I've been meaning to mess around with, which you can get over at the SPARKFUN website (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10468 ). Its a one chip graphic equalizer, used for running those little multi frequency bar graphs you see in some audio gear. To make full use of it, you do need a fair amount of external electronics. But to me it looks like you could fake it and just use some of its capability with maybe just a 555 clock and some simple logic. Might be overkill for what you want, but just the fact that the chip has built in gain might make it a good building block, with a lot of nifty future expansion possibilities.